# Convert string to Mongo ObjectID in Javascript (Meteor)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor application whereby I initially use the `_id` field from each record in my collection when naming list items in my template.

When  get the `_id` field, I convert it to a string to use in the template.

Now I want to update these records in Mongo and am passing the `_id` back to a `Meteor.method`, but these are still in string format and Mongo is expecting an ObjectID(). Is there a simple way to convert this string to the `ObjectID()`? If not, what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, found it! On the `/server`, within your Meteor method function do this to convert it:

```
var mid = new Mongo.ObjectID(str_id_sent_to_server);
```